# Piwik installation on local machine

Tags: matomo

I am trying to install piwik on my machine using XAMPP as it requires PHP, apache and mysql. When i installed XAMPP and launched apache, it worked fine but when i am trying to access MySql admin through XAMPP or access sample php page (copied on xampp/htdocs folder), apache is getting redirected to IIS which is then not able to view page, showing 404.3 error (its looking for file in wwwroot, which is also not working after pasting in wwwroot).

My objective is to make piwik up and running on my machine. Another option is Unix server which is very new to me (i have been working in Windows ). I know one should have a web server loaded with MySql and PHP to run piwik (which is hardly half an hour job once we have all these) but coz different resource available, i am struggling to get this thing done.

Any help is highly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

After two days of R&D, i figured it out (well, sort of). So for anybody who is new in piwik and in linux/apache/php/mysql, here is what i did to achieve the objective. For those of you who are familiar with all these or few of these, you might have a better way or answer and i would really request you to improve this answer but this is to help someone who is new and does not know all things at once.

Here is what i did

--get apache
--get php (one of the requirement for piwik) 
--get sql (again requirement)

--all should be running (get wamp (its carrying all three of the above)), make sure apache is running on port 80.
--install mysql but make sure only wamp's sql is running
--set passowrd for root in wamp->mysql-->mysqlConsole-->set password for 'root'@'localhost'=password('yourPasswordHere');
--Paste piwik folder in www directory
--open localhost through wamp,login in adminer and phpmyadmin (bottom right)
--run http://localhost:8080/piwik-->u will see directory listing, click on folder piwik. You should be able to see welcome screen for piwik installation

--make sure we have php 7 as selected version in wamp( for php, wamp was carrying two version so we can choose) to avoid error in system check step of installation
--Follow the steps which are very straight forward.

This is something which worked out for me. Actual answer might be simpler or better. Hope it will help someone who is probably banging his/her head around and hitting some walls without getting something concrete.

Happy to help!!!